# Changing a ToggleButton state in a ListView (getView) depending on a AlertDialog click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have this getView function, that allows me to get every click in my listview, and get the element clicked.
In every row there is a ToggleButton "boto_agregar". In my getView function there is a setOnCheckedChangeListener.. that if the togglebutton is unchecked then it is called the boolean function "DialegCancelar". Its a function that if in the AlertDialog the user clicks "Yes" the togglebutton must to be unchecked, and if the user clicks "No", then the togglebutton must to keeps checked...

What I'm doing wrong? Actually when I click "Yes" or "no" the togglebutton state doesn't change...

Thank you!

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nom_usuari = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.nom_usuari);
        viewHolder.boto_agregar = (ToggleButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar);

        viewHolder.boto_agregar.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        final int viewPosition = position;

        viewHolder.boto_agregar
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        list.get(viewPosition).setSelected(
                                buttonView.isChecked());
                        String nom = list.get(viewPosition).getName();
                        if (isChecked) {
                            SharedPreferences dades_login = context.getSharedPreferences("perfil", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            String id = dades_login.getString("id", "");
                            String[] params= {id, nom};
                            new AfegirAmic().execute(params);
                        } else {
                            if(DialegCancelar(nom,viewPosition)){
                                buttonView.setChecked(true);
                            }else{
                                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.nom_usuari, viewHolder.nom_usuari);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.boto_agregar, viewHolder.boto_agregar);

        viewHolder.boto_agregar.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        viewHolder.nom_usuari.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }


    private boolean DialegCancelar(final String nom, final int posicio)  {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder1.setMessage("Do you want to cancel the request to: "+nom+" ?");
                builder1.setCancelable(false);
                builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        SharedPreferences dades_login = context.getSharedPreferences("perfil", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String id_propia = dades_login.getString("id", "");
                        String[] params= {id_propia,nom};
                        new CancelarAmic().execute(params);
                        marcado=false;
                    }
                });
                builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        marcado=true;
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();             
        return marcado;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if(DialegCancelar(nom,viewPosition)){
         buttonView.setChecked(true);
 }else{
       buttonView.setChecked(false);
 }
```

You are checking the return value of  `DialegCancelar()` method  and setting the `buttonView`. But the method will return immediately , not after the dialog yes/no click as you expect.

So. You need to `set buttonView.setChecked` inside `Dialog` Button `onClick`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that the boolean value was returned after clicking yes or not... :) now it works!